# jQuery vertical scrolling to center on image

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

Not sure how to explain i have page with 5 images with image height that fits to height of the browser.

I want to make it that when user scrolls down page scroll bar moves but image stay centered horizontally.

Rather than starting to show half of next image.

Then when user moved scroll bar like 200px down then image shifts to next one and same thing for next and previous image.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q66bF/

I don't even know where to begin any advice is appreciated.

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d8/Manly_beach.jpg" />

<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Black%27s_beach.jpg" />

<img src="http://apollojewel.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/South-Mission-Beach-800.jpg" />

<img src="http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2011/223/9/b/boracay_beach_by_vaan37-d465ypo.jpg" />

<img src="http://www.kauaibeachscoop.com/cms/north-shore/hideaways-pali-ke-kau-beach/hideaways-beach-7-photo.jpg" />

<img src="http://cdn.tripwiremagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Piscadera-Bay-beach-wallpaper.jpg" />
```

Comment: you can use the jquery animate scrolltop. Get the offset.top of the images, you might have to set them in divs with set 100% height as the images might load later and give wrong offsets. So use get the offset.top() of the divs and save thhem in an array. Then in scroll event you can check the current document scrolltop value and compare with the other values you might have saved in an array... Hope this pulls you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript and JQuery to detect the page scroll, and use this to change the images. I created an example below, tagging each image with an ID nominating the order.

There are better ways to implement this, however this is intended as a demonstration of how to use scroll height.

you get scroll height as follows:

```
$(document).scroll(function (e) {
    var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
}
```

Demonstration below:

http://jsfiddle.net/4KvUG/embedded/result/
or
http://jsfiddle.net/4KvUG

Answer (score 0):

Here is another fiddle I made http://jsfiddle.net/medda86/5G6Ry/

you can edit theese in jquery:

```
var scrollChange = 150;
var scrollSpeed = 1000;
```